# Accessing SQLDatasource within User Control from Parent page.

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

Okay so I have been sitting on this problem for some time now. Searching for answers to no avail, well that's to say if I was using the correct keywords :(

**Scenario**

One needs a search control that can be used on a number of different pages of once website. So one builds a User Control.

**User Control setup. (Child)**

It has a couple of listboxes, textboxes, a button and SQLDatasource.
The user selects or enters a value/s in the respected field/s and click the button, the button Click event fires and gets the data from the DB and stores it into the SQLDatasource. This works all fine and dandy.

**The parent page setup.**

This contains a Gridview that has to display the data contained within the SQLDatasource that is contained in the Child.

**The problem.**

I have no idea how to access the SQLDatasource to be assigned to the Gridview.

**Questions.**

1. How can one access the SQLDatasource ?
2. Will the Gridview be able to page ?
3. If 2 is “NO” what is the alternative option to make it page ?
4. What will be the best event to assign the SQLDatasource to the
   Gridview ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are going to have the same connection string all the time, well if that is the case, just go the code behind of your user control (.ascx.cs) and try following, to bind the SqlDataSource to the asp gridview

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }
    private void LoadData()
    {
        //ConnectionStringSettingsCollection ConnctionStringCollection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
        string ConnectionString = <your connection string>;
        string SelectQuery = string.Empty;
        //if (!HasStoredProcedure)
        //    SelectQuery = QueryOrStoredProcedure;

            DashGridDataSource.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
            DashGridDataSource.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.Text;
            DashGridDataSource.SelectCommand = SelectQuery;
            DashGridDataSource.EnableCaching = true;
            DashGrid.DataSourceID = DashGridDataSource.ID;
        }
    }
```

My .ascx file looks some what as below:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DashGridWidget.ascx.cs" Inherits="*****.Widgets.DashGridDefault" %>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DashGridDataSource" runat="server" EnableCaching="true" CacheDuration="300"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="DashGrid" runat="server"
AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" onsorting="DashGrid_Sorting">
```

You may also add custom properties to your custom control in the beginning of .ascx.cs :

```
public partial class DashGridDefault : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string QueryOrStoredProcedure { get; set; }
    public bool HasStoredProcedure { get; set; }
    public int DatabaseEnum { get; set; }
```

This is how I use the control:

```
<Dashboard:IconGrid runat="server" ID="proceedings" DatabaseEnum="3" HasStoredProcedure="false" SessionVariableID="Proceeding" QueryOrStoredProcedure="SELECT TOP 100 CONTACTS FROM CUSTOMERS" />
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for the reply.
This will not work in my case AS stated in my original post that the user control (ascx.vb) contains all the necessary controls to get the data and the parent page (aspx.vb) contains the gridview. So the SQLDatasource and the Gridview are located on 2 different pages.
SQLDatasource located within the ascx.vb
Gridview located within the aspx.vb
Same questions apply as in original post.